# GRASS GIS 7.6.1 version

Tags: grass-gis

How can I download GRASS GIS 7.6.1 version while I can't find the open access online?

I am trying to install GRASS 7.6.1 for my Windows, 64-bit laptop. However, I could not find setup file for it in the GRASS GIS website (it says, "Sorry, nothing's here"). There are download files for other versions, though.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to install the very outdated version GRASS GIS 7.6.1? Current is GRASS GIS 8.3.0. Here the windows installers (recommended is to install using OSGeo4W): https://grass.osgeo.org/download/windows/

Comment: need to use this version to build SSN dictionary

Comment: Not sure what SSN dictionary is but since it is from 2019 (https://grass.osgeo.org/news/2019_03_24_grass_gis_7_6_1_released/) the outdated installers have been removed from the server time ago to save disk space.
Perhaps asking in https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-dev/ may help to find someone having a copy of the old installer file.
Alternative: take the GRASS GIS 7.6.1 source code and compile it yourself.